# Case insensitive string to replace custom comparers

Tags: c#, strings, collections

In some solutions I use case-insensitive strings a lot and so far I've been always writing custom collections or using custom comparers to support them. This is usually a lot of work and a lot of testing so I thought what if the string was case-insensitive instead?

The implementation is really simple because the `CaseInsensitiveString` is just a wrapper for a `string` that is using the `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` comparer internally. Can you think of any improvements? I use it for hash-sets or dictionaries or anything else that might require case insensitive strings.

```
public class CaseInsensitiveString : IEquatable<CaseInsensitiveString>, IEquatable<string>
{
    private readonly string value;

    public CaseInsensitiveString() { }

    public CaseInsensitiveString(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private CaseInsensitiveString(CaseInsensitiveString other)
    {
        value = other?.value;
    }

    public static CaseInsensitiveString Empty => new CaseInsensitiveString(string.Empty);

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(value);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return
            (obj is CaseInsensitiveString cis && Equals(cis)) ||
            (obj is string s && Equals(s));
    }

    public bool Equals(CaseInsensitiveString other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;
        return ReferenceEquals(this, other) || Equals(other.value);
    }

    public bool Equals(string other)
    {
        return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(value, other);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(CaseInsensitiveString obj) => obj.value;

    public static implicit operator CaseInsensitiveString(string value) => new CaseInsensitiveString(value);

    public static bool operator ==(CaseInsensitiveString left, CaseInsensitiveString right) => new CaseInsensitiveString(left).Equals(right);

    public static bool operator !=(CaseInsensitiveString left, CaseInsensitiveString right) => !(left == right);
}
```

Example usage:

```
var set = new HashSet<CaseInsensitiveString>();
set.Add("foo").Dump(); // true
set.Add("fOo").Dump(); // false

var s = (CaseInsensitiveString)"foo";
(s == "foo").Dump(); // true
(s == "fOo").Dump(); // true
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you went with this instead of forcing everything into lowercase instead? That's how I usually check case-independent and I thought this was a common approach.

Comment: @Mast you've just named the reason ;-) I don't want to think about it anymore and it's very easy to forget or to use a proper comaparison. Another reason is that you have to test all over again the same things to make sure they are really case-insensitive.

Comment: What is wrong with just initializing the collection with a case insensitive comparer?  new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Comment: @Paparazzi in certain situations you cannot force case-insensivity for example for aa property like `public ISet<string> Something { get; set; }`

Comment: @Paparazzi so you either need to create a special collection like `CaseInsensitiveSet` or simply use a different string `ISet<CaseInsensitiveString>` now I no longer have to worry about it.

Comment: Then don't worry about it.   Remember to use CaseInsensitiveString.

Comment: Is this your full class?

Comment: @Denis almost, I've just realized that I forgot to override `ToString` but yes, it's my full class but this one method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this class should be more of a wrapper class than a standalone object, something like the `Nullable<T>`.

---

[Janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/168760/98577) pointed that there are some errors with the equality of 2 null objects, but there is even more edge cases!

Take this for example:

```
CaseInsensitiveString test1 = null;
CaseInsensitiveString test2 = new CaseInsensitiveString();
Console.WriteLine(test1 == test2);
```

This will print True, but reversing the order of the items:

```
Console.WriteLine(test1 == test2);
```

Would print False.

This is also known as *Symmetric Equality*. How does `string` deal with that?

Well first off `string` doesn't have an empty constructor. I don't know all the reasons why the designers didn't include one but this could very easily be one of them. It's unclear whether the value is `null` or empty. You already provide solutions for those options which are much more understandable, you can set the value to `CaseInsensitiveString.Empty` or you can just give it a value `null`.

But let's at least try to simulate this and see the output:

```
string test1 = null;
string test2 = new string(null as char[]);
```

This will print False in both cases, because the value of `test2` would be `string.Empty`. Because your class is supposed to give just some extra functionality you should pretty much copy the behavior of the class you're '*extending*', not modify it.

---

I'm not sure if the casting should be implicit:

```
string test1 = string.Empty;
CaseInsensitiveString test2 = string.Empty;
Console.WriteLine(test1 == test2);
```

Which comparison would be used here? Can you tell me right away if you didn't know what's written in your class? If you guess correctly that the `CaseInsensitiveString` equality methods will be used, what happens with the 
`string`? Would it be treated as a normal `string` or as a `CaseInsensitiveString`?

Tho this could be just me, I haven't looked much into how some predefined .net types do the same job.

---

Besides all that, your class is extremely specific, it doesn't have any `string` instance methods or any extension methods, it doesn't inherit `IEnumerable<char>` and many characteristics that `string` has, all you can do with it is to add items to a HashMap without worrying about the letter case. The usage shrinks even more when you think about it because most collections such as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `HashSet<T>` already have a constructor which can allow you to ignore case sensitivity.

You should at the very least expose a get only property with the current `string` value, so that the user can access it from there.

An alternative would be to have all the methods implemented in your class as instance methods, but that's not a good idea, as you would still need to write 2 extension methods if you want something to be able to operate on both the `string` and your type.

Comment: The idea with the _decorator_ is very interesting and it reminds me of the [_monads series on FAIC](https://ericlippert.com/2013/02/21/monads-part-one/). I actually indend to use this type exclusively for keys/names so the other string methods are not a concern... yet. But I need to improve it.

Comment: I think I've fixed most issues already however I wonder which two extensions you mean?

Comment: @t3chb0t If there's no way to access the string value and you want to have some extension method for the string class you will need to write one for `CaseInsensitiveString` too, which would most likely modify the string before passing it to the constructor of the `CaseInsensitiveString` class, which isn't a really nice thing to have. It seems reasonable to have a `Value` property just like the `Nullable<T>` would have.

Comment: The `Nullable<T>` is cheating because it has a compiler support ;-) I can't have this advantage. Making the `value` private was acutally intentional because I don't want to loose case insensivity by accident (which is why I also made one of the operators `explicit` based on your feedback). This makes writing extensions pretty impossible without calling `ToString` first or casting but this shouldn't be necessary as I use it almost exclusively for keys, names, or ids. I've added a few more methods for strings but that should be all I ever need.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a throw-away object just to perform `==` comparison is ugly,
and likely inefficient:

> ```
> public static bool operator ==(CaseInsensitiveString left, CaseInsensitiveString right) => new CaseInsensitiveString(left).Equals(right);
> ```

I suspect you wanted to avoid a tedious null-check, but I don't think you have a choice:

```
public static bool operator ==(CaseInsensitiveString left, CaseInsensitiveString right) => !ReferenceEquals(left, null) && left.Equals(right);
```

But there's a more serious problem.
As it stands, two `null` instances of `CaseInsensitiveString` are not equal, and it should be.

Comment: You're right, I wanted to reuse the already implemented comparer.